# Hazelcast's IMap stopped working after upgrading to version 5.1.1 on K8S

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, kubernetes-cluster, autodiscovery

We have an "cache" (`javax.cache.Cache`) implementation that is a wrapper of Hazelcast's `IMap`. We use a composite Object key.

We upgraded from version 3.12.5 to 5.1.1. When I deploy the system on a local Windows machine, all works well. But when I deploy the system into an **Kubernetes environment**, the map just "does not work". Values do not get persisted into the map (after a `put` operation). An Hazelcast cluster does get formed so it does not seem to be an auto discovery issue. I also have another K8S env in which it does work properly.

I enabled Hazelcast's diagnostic mode and it does not seem to show me anything useful. I do not get any error or warn messages from the `com.hazelcast.*` package. The same issue happened also when I tried version 4.x.

I am trying to explore ways which will help to the realise what is the issue here. Thank you.

Comment: How do you configure the client? Can the client read the values it is writing? Are you sure your client connects to the cluster you are monitoring?

Comment: I work only with Hazelcast members. No clients.

Comment: I see, so what does _Values do not get persisted into the map_ mean exactly? That members don't see the values they write? That other members don't see them?

Comment: I work with a single member (pod, node) in order to reduce the complexity of the problem. Yes, a member does not see the values that it wrote. Same happens in a configuration of 2 or 2 nodes/pods/members.

Comment: Well, it looks like a misconfiguration on your application side, share your config, code how you create & access the cache etc.

Comment: After some (quite a lot...) tinkering, I noticed that the issue occurs when I set the map's max-idle value to the allowed max value, 2147483647. Still occurs if I use 2147483646, but stops if I use 214748364.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [it is a bug](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/21330). Hazelcast recommends to use the value of `0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but i was migrating from hazelcast 3.11.1 to 5.1.2, I found the IMap in  "com.hazelcast.map" not in  "com.hazelcast.core"